# Convert a list of lists to flat list of int in python

Tags: python

Hi I have a list where each element is one element list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSH9j.png

```
[['2199822281'], ['2199822390'], ['2199822392'], ['2199822369'], ['2199822370'], ['2199822284'], ['2199822281']]
```

What I want is to convert it to a list of ints in python how do I do that?

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
[2199822281, 2199822390 ...,2199822281]
```

Please refer to the image

Comment: If L1 is your list, L2 = reduce(lambda a,b : a+b , L1) followed by map(int, L2) will give your desired result, but there are several alternatives, search for them in SO archives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
x = [int(i[0]) for i in list]
```

Where `list` is the name of your list of lists above and `x` is you output list.

Comment: `i[0]`, not `i[i]`

Comment: i[0] instead of i[i]?

Comment: Good catch, I should have just pasted it in :)

Answer (score 0):

Following is another way

```
import operator
x = [['2199822281'], ['2199822390'], ['2199822392'], ['2199822369'], ['2199822370'], ['2199822284'], ['2199822281']]
print map(int, reduce(operator.add, x))
```